# Make new notifications beep every 5 minutes?

Tags: notifications, 9.0-pie, alerts

When a new message arrives, my phone lights up the screen for 2 seconds and plays a notification sound.

If you miss it, you'll never know that you have new messages, unless you turn on the screen.

Is there any way to make it beep every 5 minutes or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others reading this:

I found the option to do this hidden under `Accessibility / Advanced Settings / Notification reminders` on my Samsung.

(not the best place to put it, if you ask me)